# Setting up SSL certificates for multiple domains in GCP

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

We have a single server and want to have multiple domains pointing to that server via SSL. Tried to do the following in GCP (two different approaches):

**Approach 1:**

1. Setup a classic load balancer
2. Create a frontend service with port 443.
3. Create a Google managed certificate.
4. Add multiple domains to that certificate (a.domain1.com, b.domain1.com, a.domain2.com)
5. Setup Backend service.
6. Save

The loadbalancer spins up correctly, but we have the following issues:

1. SSL for `a.domain1.com` and `b.domain1.com` gets created, but SSL for `a.domain2.com` fails with the error `FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE`. All these are domains are setup correctly with DNS entries.
2. When I visit https://a.domain1.com, Chrome throws an error saying:
   This site can't provide a secure connection, uses an unsupported protocol.
   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

---

**Approach 2:**

Create multiple Frontends and add self managed SSL for each of them individually.
In this case, when I visit t1.domain2.com, chrome throws an error saying this certificate is invalid and pointing to t1.domain1.com

---

Question:
Any idea what I am doing wrong here? In GCP, is it possible to have a single backend service having multiple frontends pointing to it via SSL?

Comment: **fails with the error FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE**. DNS is not set up correctly or the changes you made have not propagated.  I wrote an article about solving your problem: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/dns-solving-google-managed-ssl-certificate-issue-problems/

Comment: @JohnHanley: i went through your article, still having the same SSL issue.

Comment: Did you follow any guide? Can you describe your troubleshooting process so far?